# visual studio code problem with marking lines of code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hello i  have problem with marking lines[image: vs code problem]

Comment: You're not asking a question, but what you're seeing  is [box selection](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_column-box-selection).

Comment: it is a toggle in **Selection** menu, **Column Select mode**